# Etale cohomology and Kummer theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, etale-cohomology, class-field-theory, kummer-theory

If $K$ is a field and $n \geq 1$ is such that $n \in K^{\times}$, then $H^1_{et}(\mathrm{Spec}(K),\mu_n)=K^{\times} / (K^{\times})^n$. This is easy to prove, see for instance Tamme, Etale Cohomology, Corollary 4.4.3. I assume that this is connected, perhaps even implies the main theorem from Kummer theory stating that, if $K$ has a primitive $n$th root of unity, then there is a correspondence between abelian extensions of exponent $n$ and subgroups of $K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^n$. I assume this is because $H^1_{et}(\mathrm{Spec}(K),\mu_n) = H^1_{et}(\mathrm{Spec}(K),\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is the Galois group of the maximal abelian extension of exponent $n$ of $K$? If so, can you give me a reference for this result? Sorry if this question is too basic, I didn't touch etale cohomology for years.

Comment: $H^1(K, \mu_n)$ is not equal to $H^1(K, \mathbf{Z} / n)$, but to its Pontryagin dual -- this is an instance of Tate duality.

Comment: Serre's *Galois cohomology* states this relation briefly in a remark (p. 73 in §II.1.2 of the second English edition), and refers to Bourbaki's *Algèbre* (Chap. V) for a statement of Kummer theory (but Bourbaki doesn't use Galois cohomology). In short: yes, this does imply Kummer theory with very little work.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I assumed that $K$ has a primitive $n$th root of unity. That should be sufficient for $\mu_n = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Cool! This seems to be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by R. van Dobben de Bruyn in the comments.

> "Serre's Galois cohomology states this relation briefly in a remark
> (p. 73 in §II.1.2 of the second English edition), and refers to
> Bourbaki's Algèbre (Chap. V) for a statement of Kummer theory (but
> Bourbaki doesn't use Galois cohomology). In short: yes, this does
> imply Kummer theory with very little work."